# A Column not showing in a Responsive DataTable for Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, datatable, datatables, responsive

I implemented a responsive dataTable for mobile (iPhone), it is showing all the columns except for the last column with the CRUD action links, like Edit, Details, and Delete.

[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A5No.png)

[Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wEfh.png)

The dataTable is also not showing the plus icon to expand & close certains columns. What am I missing in creating the dataTable?

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="dataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                </th>
                <th>
                    First Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Enrollment Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnrollmentDate)
                    </td>                    
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID })
                        @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                        {
                            @:|
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID })@: |

                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a JavaScript tag for responsive dataTable and the number of children of my `<tr>` element didn't match the number of `<th>` elements that were a child of the `<thead>` element."